# Is there an easy way to convert a c# enum to a string, and back again?

Tags: c#, enums

I need to convert a List of enums values to a single string to store in my db; then convert back again when I retrieve from the database.

Each enum's value is currently a simple integer, so it feels a bit overkill to create an extra table to deal with this.

So, in the example below, if the user selects Mother, Father and Sister, then the value stored in the database will be "0,1,3"

```
  public enum MyEnum
    {
        Mother = 0,
        Father = 1,
        Gran = 2,
        Sister = 3,
        Brother = 4
    }
```

I'm new to c#, so not sure if there is a nice out-the-box way to do this - I couldn't find anything obvious when google hunting!

Cheers in advance :)
 - L

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will convert back and forth between an array of Enum values via "0,1,3" as requested:

```
MyEnum[] selection = { MyEnum.Mother, MyEnum.Father, MyEnum.Sister };

string str = string.Join(",", selection.Cast<int>());

MyEnum[] enm = str.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).Cast<MyEnum>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 10):

Enum's are explicitely able to be cast to/from integers

```
int value = (int)MyEnum.Mother;
```

and

```
   MyEnum value = (MyEnum)1;
```

For strings use `ToString` and `Enum.Parse`

```
string value = MyEnum.Mother.ToString();
```

and

```
MyEnum value = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum),"Mother");
```

Comment: Those woult be `int`'s, not `string`'s as requested.

Comment: @Fredrik But he also states how to convert to string?

Comment: @Oskar: That part wasn't there when I posted the comment, I think. Either way I think I actually misread the question a bit; this looks like it's pretty much what was asked for.

Answer (score 4):

If you change you enum values to:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
    {
        Mother = 1,
        Father = 2,
        Gran = 4,
        Sister = 8,
        Brother = 16,
    }
```

Then you could store Father and Gran as 6

Sister and Brother as 24 etc

by using binary numbers you should not get duplicate values by combining them

Comment: Im interested how you can be a Sister & Brother at the same tim e:|

Comment: @Jamiec That has nothing to do with this as you do not know that selecting a value indicates that a person is that

Comment: Great - i'd forgotten about this technique!

Comment: @Jamiec - Sister and Brother at the same time would be stored as 24.

Comment: @Jamiec - just realised what you meant! hermaphrodite-tastic

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tostring.aspx) to convert to the name, and the use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse.aspx) (or [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse.aspx) if you're not on .NET 4) to convert back.

If you're wanting one enum field to contain multiple values (e.g MyEnum.Mother | MyEnum.Father), you'll need to convert that to a [`Flags` enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1zt1ybx4.aspx#Flags), as [@WraithNath suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817231/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-c-enum-to-a-string-and-back-again/4817278#4817278).  Otherwise you're talking about storing each option separately (there's no way to store `Mother` and `Father` in the same field with your current setup).

Answer (score 3):

from your code it is

```
MyEnum a = MyEnum.Mother;
string thestring = a.ToString();
MyEnum b = (MyEnum) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), thestring);
```

Answer (score 1):

String Equivelant

```
MyEnum value = MyEnum.Father;
value.ToString(); // prints Father
```

Parsing

```
(MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "Father"); // returns MyEnum.Father
```

Comment: LOL: I love it when that happens. Same comment on each other's answers.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum`s can be cast to and from integer values.  That's probably your best bet.

If you really want to use strings, `ToString` will return "Mother" "Father" "Gran" etc.  Casting back from a string would just be a function:

```
private MyEnum GetEnumValue(string fromDB)
{
    if( fromDB == "Mother" ) return MyEnum.Mother;
    else if( fromDB == "Father") return MyEnum.Father;
    //etc. etc.
}
```

EDIT:
Ian's answer for casting back is the more "C#-ey" way of doing it, and is far more extensible (handles adding new values to the enum much more flexibly).

Answer (score 0):

Further to Jamiec's suggestion (which fits well for your need), if you need to defensively code your casting, try:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), <your database value>))
{
    // Safe to convert your enumeration at this point:
    MyEnum value = (MyEnum)1;   
}
```