# Is there a way to go back to the string of a typedef enum?

Tags: c, enums

I am new with C, and I found enum really nice. My programs gets a strings, and uses the enum to do cases, and then (sometimes) I need to send back a string that matches one in a enum table. Is there a way to do it with enums or should I use lookuptables? [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817231/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-a-c-sharp-enum-to-a-string-and-back-again)

```
typedef enum    {
    string1,
    string2,
    string3,
    string4,
    BADKEY                
} strings;

function(string1); //will send the integer, 
                   //but would love to be able to send the string.

function(char *string) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, there are some good idea there. @QuentinUK Could you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: Also considering it is really similar (if not the same) to the previous question should I delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way to get this automatically. You must implement a way, look-up tables is one solution.

The names of enum values are not "strings", they're just symbols like function and variable names; they play no role in the code generation. Once the code runs, it's all machine code with no names left.

Comment: :( soo much info lost. This is the answer I fear, but thanks for clearing it up.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, You could make use of the preprocessor's "stringify" operator.

```
#define MAKE_STR(enumMember) #enumMember
```

What this does is that it replaces enumMember with "enumMember" so you could use it as you would a string.

example:

```
printf("The value of %s is %d", MAKE_STR(string1), string1);
```

**EDIT** Note though that what stringify does is just surrounds whatever it's passed with quotes, so it literally stringifies whatever is written after the #.